# PHP: Amount of bytes fread

Tags: php, io, fread

Say I read a number of bytes like this:

```
$data = fread($fp, 4096);
```

Since `fread` will stop reading if it reaches the end of the file, how can I know exactly how much was read? Would `strlen($data)` work? Or could that be potentially wrong?

---

What I'm trying to accomplish, is to read a number of bytes, and then go back to where I was before I read. And I'm trying to avoid using arithmetic (`ftell`, `fread`, `ftell`, subract, `fseek`), since a file could potentially be larger than `PHP_INT_MAX` and potentially mess that up. What I would want is to just do `fseek($fp, -$bytes_read, SEEK_CUR)`, but for that I need to know how many bytes I just read...

Comment: @OZ_, Since `strlen` returns the length of a string, I am wondering if stuff like character encoding and stuff could mess things up for example.

Comment: Your contradicting yourself a little, how can you go back to a position without using `fseek` ?

Comment: @RobertPitt, No no, I of course need to use `fseek`. The issue is how to get a correct, relative number of bytes to jump backwards. I don't want to have to use `ftell`, that's all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this (untested):

```
mb_strlen($data, '8bit')
```

The second argument `'8bit'` forces the function to return the number of bytes.

Found in comments at [php manual for mb_strlen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php).

Comment: `mb_strlen()` returns the number of characters read, not the number of bytes (like specified as the second argument of `fread()`). You should use `strlen()` here.

Comment: Forcing mb_strlen in 8bit will read bytes. Although strlen would originally read bytes, it might have been overloaded to use mb_strlen. And there is not an easy way to be sure this has happened. Rendering it useless if you need to be sure you're counting bytes. See http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.overload.php

Answer (score 6):

After `fread` use [`ftell($fp)`](http://php.net/manual/function.ftell.php) to get the current file position.